# Fabricjs after object move programmatically its not selectable on its new position

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have tried to move the object programmatically and get success, but after the object is moved by programmatic way, its not able to select the object by selecting the object current position, still the object is selectable from by its old position I have tried with `canvas.calcOffset();` still its not working.

How can I make the object selectable in its current position the code I have used as follows

**Javascript**

```
 var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
 canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({                    
                    left:100,
                    top: 100,
                    width: 75,
                    height: 50,
                    fill: 'white',
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    padding: 10,
                    selectable: true
             }));


function changePosition()
{
    canvas.item(0).set({left:300});
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"/>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="changePosition()" value="Change Possition"/>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirumalaimurugan/a99L7/)

**Steps to reproduce the error**

1. Click the <kbd>Change Position</kbd> button
2. Try selecting the rectangle on its current position, and move to the cursor to the plave where the object was previously there you will be able to select the object

Comment: `canvas.item(0).setCoords()`

Comment: @kangax thank you much. its seems to be bug because if its moved it should be updated its co-ordinates is it.

Comment: @kangax I am trying to build the collaborative white board, I want to draw the line, ex: when teacher draw the line all students whiteboard should be updated the drawing how can I do that?

Comment: well you gotta break your task into small ones and ask about whatever is still unclear here or on Fabric's google group

Answer (score 40):

you need to fire setCoords() method once if you are changing object's position programmatically. This will set Coords of your object to new position.

Comment: thanks @innodel this has been answered by kangax very long back please check the comment below my question.

Comment: I just realized that even when you change selection padding programmatically, you need to call `setCoords()` to adjust corners click area. Thank you !